# Error when running windows service in release mode on servers

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I am getting error in below code (in constructor) only when I run the Published version (release version) on Servers (as window service). But the same code work fine when I run the windows service locally in debug build. I have

```
public class MyDataProcess
{
        IEventLogger _log;

        public MyDataProcess()
        {
            _log = new EventLogger();
            _log.SetTaskProcessor("MyDataProcess");
        }
}
```

I'll appreciate any help on the above issue.

**Error:**

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at MyJobs.MyDataProcess..ctor()    at
>   MyJobs.MainProcessor.d__5.MoveNext()

Answer (score 0):

ensure the account running the service has the privilege to write on system log, that's likely the cause of your problem

(EventLogger is your right? check if inside you try to create a new EventLog)